# Using two separate CSS frameworks in same Rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

Right now I have an app which frontend is coded with `Bootstrap 3` (I'm using `bootstrap-rails` gem). I would like to use also `Materialize.css` framework in the same app so I downloaded its stylesheet. My question is how to make these two frameworks play well together? I require `Materialize.css` stylesheet in my `Application.scss` file like so:

```
*= require 'materialize'
```

but current styles are seem to be mixed (I mean `Bootstrap` and `Materialize.css` styles try to override each other).
Is it even possible to make them work together or should I create different `Application.html` file for the parts I wanna use second CSS framework anyway?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want styles from both frameworks in your entire app, or just to style a specific component within the app?

Comment: Take a look at css modules https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules may be it fits your case

Comment: @dommmm yes, I'd like to have styles from both frameworks in entire app.

Comment: since you're using the bootstrap gem for your app already, you should ideally just cherry pick the stuff you want from materialize, instead of importing it wholesale. Get the sass version of the framework, and import the parts you want.

Comment: @dommmm thanks for suggestion, I already thought about it. Googling als made me think that there a only two ways: either create two separate layouts or import everything I need from sass.
Please write your post as an aswer, I'll mark as a right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you are already using the bootstrap gem for your app, so you should ideally just cherry-pick the stuff you want from materialize, instead of importing the framework wholesale. Get the sass version of the framework, and import the parts you want.